# Access client side source for ios

Tags: javascript, swift

Is it possible to access client side part of the iOS application?

For example; at web if we do "view page source"; we could see everything. The  tags and anything web is accessible even the client sided AJAX requests.

For instance; if I wanted to learn about an specific app more; and want to learn how they handle client side of the things; how would I go on about it? I'm not just trying to inspect HTTP calls; I know about wireshark and mitmproxies; more of like the source code part for client sides. Like how it's possible to get JS client side on web apps.

Comment: Short answer? No. Longer answer? With "web" you need to remember that the "source" is what *is* on the client - and yes, that means you *cannot* see what is on the web server, only what is pushed to the client *via* HTTP. That AJAX request? You can't see what is happening on the server. Now with an iOS app, there *is* no "source" on the client, only an executable.

Comment: What are executables? Can you please give me an example thanks! @dfd

Comment: Apologies. Ive been in IT since 1984 - long before "the web" - and I expected you knew. Essentially it's a *binary* file. There's more to it - code signing, etc. - but unlike HTML, which *everything* done on "the web" is, it's *not* text. When you get down to it - the web (encrypted or not) is text markup. Apps aren't. They are like trying to see the source to Microsoft Office.

Comment: Gotcha! So what I meant by source was those executables files you described. I'm trying to learn the authentication process of an application. Therefore essential for me to learn how they generate those tokens.

Comment: Can't help you there. I know just enough about code signing and such to be dangerous. But I should point out that very little in your question told me that you were looking for that. (You even included the word "source" in the title.) Good luck!